# Laravel 5.3 Flash message no showing

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have page in which I have two tabs one for insert data and one for showing data in ajax datatable, I have only one problem and that is Flash messages are not displaying with success or with errors.

What I already did:

- there was only one 302 response after redirect.
- blade part for showing errors is already there.
- I am using withErrors($model->errors()).
- I also tried to put data manually in session but no luck.

Here is my controller part.

```
 if (!$party->save()) {                   
                    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($party->errors())->with('selected_tab',
                        '#create_case'); //I do not need input values only top flash messages
                }
```

Http/routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'XSSProtection'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'namespace' => 'Modules\Cases\Http\Controllers'],
        function () {

            // these routes apply to logged users only
            Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
                ### only roles with permissions can access these routes
                Route::group(['middleware' => 'acl', 'protect_alias' => 'case_checklist'], function () {

                    Route::resource('checklist', 'CheckListController');
                    //GET
                    Route::get('checklist.edit/{id}/{source}', 'CheckListController@edit')->name('checklist.edit');
                    Route::get('getCaseDetails', 'CheckListController@getCaseDetails')->name('getCaseDetails');
                    Route::get('create/{id}/{source}', 'CheckListController@createCheckList')->name('create');
                    Route::get('pending/{id}/{source}', 'CheckListController@pendingChecklist')->name('pending');

                    Route::get('approval/{id}/{source}/{is_checklist_approved?}',
                        [
                            'uses' => 'CheckListController@approvalChecklist',
                            'can' => 'update.approval_checklist'
                        ]
                    )->name('approval');


                    Route::get('download/{id}', 'CheckListController@downloadFile')->name('download');
                    Route::get('view_councel', 'CheckListController@viewCouncel')->name('view_councel');

                    //POST
                    Route::post('checklist.update/{id}', 'CheckListController@update')->name('checklist.update');
                    Route::post('clubCases', 'CheckListController@clubCases')->name('clubCases');
                    Route::post('assignCounsel', 'CheckListController@assignCounsel')->name('assignCounsel');

                    Route::post('recommend',
                        [
                            'uses' => 'CheckListController@recommendCounsel',
                            'can' => 'update.counsel_recommend'
                        ]
                    )->name('recommend');

                    Route::post('checklist_reject',
                        [
                            'uses' => 'CheckListController@checklistReject',
                            'can' => 'update.checklist_rejection'
                        ]
                    )->name('checklist_reject');

                    Route::post('storeCheckList', 'CheckListController@storeCheckList')->name('storeCheckList');
                    Route::patch('storeCounsel', 'CheckListController@storeCounsel')->name('storeCounsel');
                    Route::post('approve', 'CheckListController@approveChecklist')->name('approve');

                    //AJAX
                    Route::get('getInfo', 'AjaxController@getChecklistInfo')->name('getInfo');
                    Route::get('dropdownJSON', 'AjaxController@getDropdownJSON')->name('dropdownJSON');
                    Route::get('checklistJSON', 'AjaxController@getChecklistJSON')->name('checklistJSON');
                    Route::post('showChecklist', 'AjaxController@showChecklist')->name('showChecklist');
                    Route::get('showClubCases', 'AjaxController@showClubCases')->name('showClubCases');
                    Route::get('getChecklistDocs', 'AjaxController@getChecklistDocuments')->name('getChecklistDocs');
                    Route::post('storeNewCheckListDocument', 'AjaxController@storeNewCheckListDocument')->name('storeNewCheckListDocument');
                    Route::get('getCounsels', 'AjaxController@getCounsels')->name('getCounsels');
                    Route::get('getLawFirmBranches', 'AjaxController@getLawFirmBranches')->name('getLawFirmBranches');
                    Route::get('getCounselsAjax', 'AjaxController@getCounselsAjax')->name('getCounselsAjax');
                    Route::get('getChecklistS', 'AjaxController@getChecklistS')->name('getChecklistS');


                });
                ### only roles with permissions can access these routes
                Route::group(['middleware' => 'acl', 'protect_alias' => 'counsel_create'], function () {
                    Route::get('createCounsel/{id}/{source}',
                        'CheckListController@goToCreateCounsel')->name('createCounsel');
                });

            });
        });
});
```

Included blade part

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger red-text animated shake">
        <strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> We found some errors:</strong><br>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Http/Kernel

```
/**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

One 302 response in chroem network tab:

[image: response]

I am using clockwork extension here are sessions for both post/get request

[image: Post]

[image: GET]

Comment: Would you check `dd($party)` inside of the if statement? Has it errors actually or not?

Comment: Try removing `'middleware' => 'web'` from the second route group. Laravel 5.2 changed the routes so that they are already loaded within the web middleware by default, and including it twice messes with the sessions. But, I'm not sure how your routes are loaded, as you mentioned 5.3 in the title, but 5.3 does not use the `app\Http\routes.php` file.

Comment: #YaserKH Yes If I use dd($party->errors()) it shows the errors before redirect backs

Comment: #patricus It is Laravel 5.3 but I have modules inside every module I have http->routes.php file and main routes->web.php is just empty